# Invalid set index 'text' (on base: 'Nil') godot

Tags: gd, godot, gdscript

I'm not new to both coding and Godot and was trying to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nR0nCFJ8-qM&t=1084s) tutorial but I keep getting the same error

> Invalid set index 'texture' (on base: 'TextureButton (ITEM_SPRITE.gd)') with value of type 'StreamTexture'.

my code in the item class is:

```
tool
extends Resource

class_name ITEM

export(String) var ITEM_NAME
export(int) var QUANT
export(String, MULTILINE) var HOVER_TEXT
export(Texture) var ITEM_TEXTURE 

func addQuant(addedQuant :int):
    QUANT += addedQuant

func getTexture() -> Texture:
    return ITEM_TEXTURE

func getHover() -> String:
    return HOVER_TEXT
```

This is the code for item sprite which should read `ITEM_TEXTURE` and set it to its own texture:

```
tool
extends TextureButton

export(Resource) var item setget setItem

onready var labelText = $RichTitemextLabel


func addQuant(addedQuant :int):
    item.addQuant(addedQuant)


func setItem(newItem : Resource):
    item = newItem
    
    self.texture = item.getTexture()
    labelText.text = str(newItem.getHover())
```

I have tried changing the variable type of the texture var to `StreamTexture` and that did nothing, the actual item that uses the class works fine it is just the item sprite that can't read it for some reason. I have looked at a similar post but because my texture is an exported variable idk if change that if it is a problem

it should read the texture from the item and display it (but it is just returning the error)

sorry for the stupid question & please help if you can

Answer (score 1):

`TextureButton` does not have a `texture` property. It has multiple!

- `texture_disabled`
- `texture_focused`
- `texture_hover`
- `texture_normal`
- `texture_pressed`

Thus, trying to set `texture` fails. You got to decide which are you going to set according to the state the `Texture` is for.

Yes, each of those properties is for a different states of the `BaseButton`. I talk more about the states of button ins another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71313296/402022).

Answer (score 0):

thank you for being so helpful i appreciate it, and I changed `self.texture` to `self.texture_normal` and it worked